# libdovecot-sieve.so.0 undefined symbol: i_debug

Tags: dovecot, debian-wheezy, sieve

After upgrading dovecot from 1.2 to 2.1.7 (while upgrading squeeze to wheezy) sieve no longer does it's job. (And breaks mail delivery)

apt-purging all dovecot packages and reinstalling did not improve the situation, i still get the same error message:

```
==> mail.err <==
Mar 14 13:40:14 xxx dovecot: deliver(postmaster@xxx.de): dlopen(/usr/lib/dovecot/modules//lib90_sieve_plugin.so) failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0: undefined symbol: i_debug
Mar 14 13:40:14 xxx dovecot: deliver(postmaster@xxx.de): Fatal: Couldn't load required plugins

==> mail.info <==
Mar 14 13:40:14 xxx postfix/pipe[15828]: 13B1F19E0792: to=<xxx@xxx.de>, orig_to=<xxx@xxx.de>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.43, delays=0.32/0.01/0/0.09, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure)
```

dovecot.conf:

```
protocols = imap lmtp sieve

mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/

[snip]
...
[/snip]

protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
  #mail_plugins = sieve
}

protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}


plugin {
  #recipient_delimiter = +
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
```

ll /usr/lib/dovecot/libdovecot-siev*

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Feb  5  2013 libdovecot-sieve.so -> libdovecot-sieve.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 Feb  5  2013 libdovecot-sieve.so.0 -> libdovecot-sieve.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  540304 Feb  5  2013 libdovecot-sieve.so.0.0.0
```

ll /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/*sieve*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18392 Feb  5  2013 /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved:

in postfix mails were piped to dovecot's deliver istead of lmtp

deleting the pipe in /etc/postfix/master.cf,

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
 flags=DORhu user=nobody argv=/usr/local/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender}
 -d ${user}@${nexthop} -n -m ${extension}
```

and adding a virtual trasport to /etc/postfix/main.cf,

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

or

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/dovecot/lmtp
```

fixed the issue for me